# store a php array in session from input form

Tags: php, arrays, session

I am having allot of trouble trying to get an array to work with sessions if anyone can help that would be great I'm not bothered about validation etc if I can just get it working i can then expand upon it.

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="array2.php">
    Select amount of tickets you require.
    <select name="options[]">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
    Select the acomidation you require.
    <select name="options2[]">
        <option value="camping">Camping</option>
        <option value="caravan">Caravan</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go!" />
</form>
```

array2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$checked = $_POST['options'];
$checked2 = $_POST['options2'];
$_SESSION['user'] = true;
$_SESSION['checked'] = $checked;
$_SESSION['checked2'] = $checked2;
header('Location: array3.php');
?>
```

array3.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    die("To access this page, you need to <a href='register.html'>LOGIN</a>");
}
$checked = $_SESSION['checked'];
$checked2 = $_SESSION['checked2'];
?>

<?php
    for($i=0; $i < count($checked && $checked2); $i++){
        echo "You have selected to receive " . $checked[$i] . " tickets<br/>";
        echo "And you have selected to receive " . $checked2[$i] . " for accommodation are you sure? <br/>";
    }
?>
```

The main problem is that the values are not being passed from `array2` into `array3`, any help is welcomed.

EDIT - this worked fine until I tried to add in the sessions to get it working over multiple pages so I'm sure thats where the problem is

EDIT2 - thanks for all the help guys i got it working when I took out

```
$checked = $_POST['options'];
$checked2 = $_POST['options2'];
```

From array 3 it worked :) much appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you getting value in `array2` & not in `array3` ? , if you can cross check for me.

Comment: What does a `print_r($_SESSION)` return in array3.php?

Comment: use the power of print_r($_SESSION); after session_start(); in array3.php

Comment: I took out the redirect header on array2, and added in the for statement into array 2 and it works fine if that is what you mean

Comment: using print session i get
Array ( [user] => 1 [checked] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [checked2] => Array ( [0] => camping ) ) You have selected to recive tickets
And you have selected to recive for accommodation are you sure?

Comment: What is the error message you get in array3.php? is it the die() statement?

Answer (score 4):

```
count($checked && $checked2)
```

...is your problem.

`$checked && $checked2` is a logical expression will either be `true` or `false`, which means thats the `count()` call will always return `false`, and `false` will equate to `0` in a numeric comparison (the less than `<` comparison with `$i`), so the for loop won't perform any iterations.

However, the use of arrays in this situation is not appropriate anyway, because you have used a `<select>` element without a `multiple` property so it will only represent a single value, which means the array would only ever hold a single value. You should simplify this to just scalar values and you will find that a) it works and b) it's much easier in general.

Comment: okay i will work on that, i got it working by removing the
$checked = $_POST['options'];
$checked2 = $_POST['options2'];
and it works but i will look into what you are saying.

Comment: yeh i will look into that, I've only been doing php for the last 6 weeks, really just trying to get the basics done the idea behind using both in the same statement was that if you have tickets selected then you must have accommodation hopefully i turn it into a better statement but really fow what i currently know i cant do much better than that for now.

Answer (score 2):

Your for loop is written wrong.

```
for($i=0; $i < count($checked && $checked2); $i++)
```

That count statement will not work as you think. Break it into 2 for loops or an inner loop.

like this:

```
for($i=0; $i < count($checked); $i++){
  echo stuff here
}

for($i=0; $i < count($checked2); $i++){
  echo stuff here
}
```